# Woocommerce create order using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've managed to get this 90% of the way there but I'm having problems with the final step.

I've got 3 coupons set up in WooCommerce that I've linked to s2Member, when a user signs up using a coupon up I've managed to get the script to create an order in WooCommerce from some variables defined in my script.

Problem is, when there's no coupon code present - the order isn't created!

Here's the snippet of code where the problem lies. I'm suspecting it's because of the way I'm using if, else if and else. I'm really not a PHP pro so any advice would be amazing.

Thanks.

```
if ($coupon_code == 'qwerty35') {
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( get_product( $tier ), 1 );
$order->add_coupon($coupon_code, 6.65 );
$order->set_total( 6.65, 'order_discount' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->payment_complete();      
}
elseif ($coupon_code == 'asdfg35') {
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( get_product( $tier ), 1 );
$order->add_coupon($coupon_code, 6.65 );
$order->set_total( 6.65, 'order_discount' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->payment_complete();      
}
elseif ($coupon_code == 'zxcvb35') {
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( get_product( $tier ), 1 );
$order->add_coupon($coupon_code, 6.65 );
$order->set_total( 6.65, 'order_discount' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->payment_complete();      
}
else {
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( get_product( $tier ), 1 );
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->payment_complete();      
    }
```

Comment: Not your problem but you should try to apply the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle, the code would be much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: This piece of code does exactly the same than yours. `$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product(get_product($tier), 1);
$order->set_address($address, 'billing');
$order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
if ($coupon_code == 'qwerty35' || $coupon_code == 'asdfg35' || $coupon_code == 'zxcvb35') {
    $order->add_coupon($coupon_code, 6.65);
    $order->set_total(6.65, 'order_discount');
}
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->payment_complete();`

Comment: Thanks @gbesterd I know the codes a little iffy, I'm really still very much a beginner. Just can't figure out why the order isn't going through when there's no coupon present.